# Implementing Rest Api JAVA client android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, client

I am a newbie to Android development so apologies if i am missing something obvious here. I am using Eclipse to put together a simple Android program that will consume a couple of Rest web services. I am attempting to use the Resting API to accomplish this.

I have copied the Resting JAR file into the libs folder of my project and its in the build path however I can't reference any of the Resting classes, i attempt to include the appropriate imports but they fail to resolve.

Has anyone got a complete sample of using Resting to consume a restful web service? Should I look to use a different library perhaps? Simplicity is key for me so the lighter the library the better.

Thanks hugely for any advice you may have

Answer (score 2):

I think the resting jar file may be an archive file which in turn contains all the jar files required to use resting. You need to open the archive using a tool like winrar, extract all the jars inside, put them in the lib folder of your project and reference.

Resting seems fairly simple and lightweight. Mostly, one step.

Comment: That's right, it seems to be a jar file which contains another jars, and those are the ones you need to import.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Resting API but I have used [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) and it is easy to use. Give it a try. As per the referencing things, things should resolve once you add the dependencies. You might need to read a bit how Eclipse handles that.

Comment: Thanks, I went for the Apache HTTP libraries

Answer (score 0):

Resting sample code:

List products = new RestingBuilder("http://myapis.com/productservice",Product.class)
      .setPort(8080)
      .setVerb(Verb.GET)
      .setTransformationType(TransformationType.JSON)
      .setConnectionTimeout(3000)
      .build();